# Android Two-way binding and @InverseBindingAdapter doesn't work in Modular Architecture project

Tags: android, two-way-binding, modularization, android-multi-module

Having Modular Architecture project. Reusable custom views are being moved to core-ui module. Features (fragments, sheets, etc) at the moment are still in app module.

Before migrating custom views with `@InverseBindingAdapter` (two-way binding) from app to core-ui module everything worked fine. After moving custom `SearchView` with it's two-way bindings to separate module those binding errors appeared.

```
The attribute 'app:queryAttrChanged' is generated and reserved for two-way data binding so an expression cannot be assigned to it
```

Moving back to app module, everything works fine.

All other custom views with `@BindingAdapter` (one way binding) works fine after migrating to core-ui. So something is wrong with `@InverseBindingAdapter`.

I wasn't able to find any Modular Architecture Android project, which would use two-way binding in it. Also zero search results were found for error provided above. Any ideas where could be the problem?

```
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["queryAttrChanged"])
    fun setQueryAttrChanged(searchView: SearchView, listener: InverseBindingListener) {
        searchView.binding?.viewSearchText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                listener.onChange()
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) = Unit
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) = Unit
        })
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("query")
    fun setQuery(searchView: SearchView, value: String?) {
        if (value != searchView.binding?.viewSearchText?.text.toString()) {
            searchView.binding?.viewSearchText?.setText(value)
        }
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "query")
    fun getQuery(searchView: SearchView): String {
        return searchView.binding?.viewSearchText?.text.toString()
    }
```

```
        <com.foo.com.core_ui.utils.ui.views.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:query="@={viewmodel.mutableLiveData.searchQuery}"
            app:queryAttrChanged="@{() -> viewmodel.onSearchQueryChanged()}" />
```